# How to send array data as a parameter for get value in Laravel controller?

Tags: laravel, model-view-controller, get

This is My code which is used in function -

```php
foreach($allcourses as $allcourse) {
  $tl_class[] = $allcourse['title_of_class'];
  // $trn_email[] = $allcourse['trainer_email'];
}
$rating = new RatingController;
Log::info(print_r($tl_class, true). ' : RatingController tl_class data');
```

I want to send array data a parameter as below-

```php
$rating = new RatingController;
$rating_data = $rating->getAllPublicRatting($tl_class);
```

but Showing error. So, How to pass this array value as a parameter?

Comment: What error did you get?

Comment: Call to a member function all() on array {"userId":40,"email":"ajay@gmail.com","exception":"[object] (Symfony\\Component\\Debug\\Exception\\FatalThrowableError(code: 0): Call to a member function all() on array at C:\\xampp\\htdocs\\ds-student-ms\\app\\Http\\Controllers\\PassportAPI\\ClassController.php:27)

Answer (score 1):

```
$tl_class[];
foreach ($allcourses as $allcourse) {
            tl_class->push($allcourse['title_of_class']);
           // $trn_email[] = $allcourse['trainer_email'];
        }
```

you need to push data to your array cause your each loop when return always your array define empty.